# Android GridView Adapter to Populate Multiple Sections

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-fragments, adapter

It is my desire to use multiple adaptable [GridViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) to populate several sections on the screen with different data. There is an undetermined amount of sections, and items in each section so the solution must be flexible. Each section will have a section header title and its own gridview, filled with an unknown number of items. These elements must be clickable to take you to another screen for that element. So the desired screen would look something like this:

```
 __________________________________
|         **Section1**             |
|                                  |
| GridView1  GridView1  GridView1  |
| Item1      Item2      Item3      |
|                                  |
| GridView1  GridView1             |
| Item4      Item5                 |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|         **Section2**             |
|                                  |
| GridView2  GridView2  GridView3  |
| Item1      Item2      Item3      |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|         **Section3**             |
|                                  |
| GridView3  GridView3             |
| Item1      Item2                 |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|         **Section4**             |
|                                  |
| GirdView4  GridView4  GridView4  |
| Item1      Item2      Item3      |
|__________________________________|
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some fiddling around I figured out a solution to my question by programmatically rendering each gridview and header:

Using a basic layout like this (since the number of gridviews needed is unknown):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/appListFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
```

And a buildAdapter method in the fragment like so:

```
boolean headerSectionsRendered = false;
...
private void buildAdapter() {
    String gridViewIdString;

    /* fill the adapter */
    for (String category : mApps.keySet()) {
      /* get all of the apps for current category */
      mAppAdapter = new AppsAdapter(getActivity(), mApps.get(category));

      /* begin programmatically creating the view */
      LinearLayout appListLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity()
          .findViewById(R.id.appListFragment);

      /* create the section header */
      TextView appSectionHeader = new TextView(getActivity());
      appSectionHeader.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      appSectionHeader.setText(category);
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) appSectionHeader
          .getLayoutParams();
      params.setMargins(15, 8, 15, 5); // left, top, right, bottom
      appSectionHeader.setLayoutParams(params);
      appSectionHeader.setTextSize(16);

      /* create GridView for the current section*/
      GridView appSectionGridView = new GridView(getActivity());
      appSectionGridView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      appSectionGridView.setVerticalSpacing(10);
      appSectionGridView.setHorizontalSpacing(10);
      appSectionGridView.setNumColumns(3);
      appSectionGridView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
      appSectionGridView.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
      appSectionGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {
          /* position of clicked app and adapter it was located in */
          showApp(position, parent.getAdapter());
        }
      });

      if (!headerSectionsRendered) {
        headerCount++;
        appSectionGridView.setAdapter(mAppAdapter);
        appListLayout.addView(appSectionHeader);
        appListLayout.addView(appSectionGridView);
      }
      if (headerCount == mApps.keySet().size()) {
        headerSectionsRendered = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

With an Apps adapter that looks like this:

```
private class AppsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Activity mContext;
    private final App[] apps;

    public AppsAdapter(Activity context, App[] appList) {
      mContext = context;
      apps = appList;
    }

    public int getCount() {
      return apps.length;
    }

    public App getItem(int position) {
      return apps[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View gridItem;

      gridItem = new View(mContext);
      /* app_cell is the layout for the individual items */
      gridItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_cell, null);
      ImageView appIcon = (ImageView) gridItem.findViewById(R.id.app_cell_icon);
      TextView appTitle = (TextView) gridItem.findViewById(R.id.app_cell_title);

      if (appIcon != null && appTitle != null) {
        mContext.loadImage(apps[position].getIcon(), appIcon);
        appTitle.setText(apps[position].getTitle());
      }

      return gridItem;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
      return 1;
    }
  }
```

I did not include all the specific details of how I implemented this solution, but if you would be curious to learn more or have any comments or suggestions please let me know!

Comment: any idea how to achieve this solution ? i also  want to  dispay gridview with alreay known numbers of section but every section will contain header and footer